# How to set default redirect with different session on laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, permissions

I have a manage login with roles . its user ,admin ,superadmin . i create this all roles in middleware , and at this code in LoginController :

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ( $user->isAdmin() ) {
        return redirect()->route('admin_dashboard');
    }
    elseif ($user->isSuperadmin()) {
        return redirect()->route('superadmin_dashboard');
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

}
```

its work normaly , if i login admin its redirect to admin_dashboard , **but**  this problem is , if i **close** this browser and run localhost:8000 , its redirect to **home** not **admin_dashboard** .

my question , how i can set if **login as admin** and close the browser and run localhost:8000 its going to admin_dashboard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create multiple guards according to roles name like 'admin','superamdin'.

Here is link for create multiauth in laravel .
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKRLrJXNN4M&t=1s

After your create multiple guards you can just use middleware to redirect authenticated user.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    switch ($guard) {
        case 'admin':
            if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
            }
            break;

        case 'superadmin':
            if (Auth::guard('superadmin')->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('superadmin.dashboard');
            }
            break;

        default:
            //user gaurd
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect('/');
            }
            break;
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

**Second Option**

Store authentication details in cookie and while staring app just check once to redirect accordingly.

Comment: i just need a make guard for admin and superadmin ?

Comment: not just guard but register and login controller also....if you want source code i can give you

Comment: can you give me ? i have a problem here

Comment: can you give me your mail id ?

Comment: adhik13th@gmail.com